# PHP Curl get information from the page with redirect

Tags: php, json, redirect, curl, get

I have a page A, it has location header that redirects to the page B

On the page B if not authorized then there is a login form printed, if logged in then it redirects back to page A with GET parameter CODE. **Page A code:**

```
if (!$_GET['code']) {
header('Location: B');
}
```

Page A uses this code to get information from the server addressing again to page B, but this time with CURL. **Page A code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
..
curl_opt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "B/token?code={SOMECODE}");
..
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($data);
```

Now I have JSON data that I continue to use on page A. **Page A code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
..
curl_opt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "B/method/?data={SOMEDATA_FROM_$result}");
..
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($result);

$json = [
'key1' => $response->value1,
'key2' => $response->value2,
];

echo json_encode($json);
```

So now I have printed JSON data on page A.

Here comes page C, where I use curl to get this JSON data from page A, but page A redirects to page B, where we have to authorize, and get GET parameter CODE. So I use curl to do it. **Page C code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'A');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

And `$result` returns HTML code of the authorization form from page B, even though Im authorized, but it only does it with `var_dump()` if I use `echo` it starts to refresh page infinitely.

How can I get correct data from page A using `curl` on page C?

Comment: Ok, so the structure was wrong. I came up with not using curl on page C, just a simple link from page C to page A, with GET parameter as a back redirect link to page C. Now I just authorize the user on page B, send data to page A, do all the stuff that I need, and send data to page C with POST request.

Answer (score 0):

is page A and page C on same server? if so, set a condition in page C, if the client ip = 127.0.0.1 then skip the login process and response the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the structure was wrong. I add the sheme so you see how it works now.

[image]

I came up with not using curl on page C, just a simple link from page C to page A, with GET parameter as a back redirect link to page C. Now I just authorize the user on page B, send data to page A, do all the stuff that I need, and send data to page C with POST request.

How it works? - Simple, when I send redirect uri from C to A with GET request, I start session on page A. Now I authorize on page B (page B knows nothing about page C!!), and get back to page A, where I have all the functions needed to work with the response of authorization, get all needed data, and echo it as json. And in the and I just POST all the user data to script on page C.

So now I have all the information on client-site C. And Im free to do whatever I need with it.

So the code is like this:

```
----- Page C -----

<a href="pageA.php?redirect_uri=pageC.php">Login</a>

----- Page A -----

session_start();

$redirect = isset($_GET['redirect_uri']) ? $_GET['redirect_uri'] : null;
$code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : null;

if ($code) {
$redirect = $_SESSION['redirect'];
session_destroy();

// The simple way to send data back with GET request
header("Location:{$redirect}?code={$code}");

}

if (!$redirect) {
throw new Exception('Redirect URI is required');
}

$_SESSION['redirect'] = $redirect;

header('Location: PageB.php');
```